# How to create logbak.properties for TimeBasedRollingPolicy

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging

I want generate logs on day basis, so here is my `logbak.xml` which works fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<appender name="SAVE-TO-FILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern> %d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>/Users/administrator/Desktop/app/logs/log_%d{dd-MM-yyyy}.log
            </fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>

    </appender>
        <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="SAVE-TO-FILE" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

However, I want to achieve the same thing by using `logbak.properties` file. But I could find any example for `TimeBasedRollingPolicy`. I could not find attribute for rolling policy in [common-application-properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

```
logging.path= //file path   
logging.file= //file name       
logging.pattern.file= //file logging pattern
**What is for TimeBasedRollingPolicy ??**
```

**In short how to give rolling policy in .properties file??**

Answer (score 0):

Slf4j is a logging abstraction that you can include in your project by just including the api jar. You are free to use any logging implementation like log4j or logback.
So you can use Log4J by simple providing the dependency in maven:

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.0-beta0</version>
</dependency>
```

And then create a config file **log4j.properties** and put following contents :

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, loggerId  
log4j.appender.loggerId=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender  
log4j.appender.loggerId.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout  
log4j.appender.loggerId.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n  
log4j.appender.loggerId.File=d:/logs/example  
log4j.appender.loggerId.DatePattern='-'yyyyMMdd'.log'
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: There might be your logbak logging is getting picked instead of log4j. So you first need to remove that from class path..